# Google Analytics redirects to 'www.google.com/analytics/provision/' on clicking 'View Report'

Tags: google, google-analytics

After logging in to my Analytics account I can see all the reports I have available (I'm administrator for all). But upon clicking 'View Report' I get redirected to the page:

https://www.google.com/analytics/provision/

A quick search turns up a number of threads in Google Groups regarding the same problem, but no viable solutions are suggested.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is the Google account you use for Analytics a Google Apps account?

Comment: Yeah, it is my apps account. Perhaps another issue since the migration to a full Google Account on my part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem, but so far Google has been completely unresponsive in the [help forums](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Analytics/label?lid=52d2f6b99ad2350e&hl=en).

So far the only workaround I have is, since you still have access to the administration functions, to give view access to a another Google account of yours (many of the people who have reported this problem are using Google Apps account, so I used my regular Google account just to be safe). It's very annoying to have to log in and out all the time or use a separate browser, because Analytics doesn't support multiple sign-in, but at least you'll be able to see your reports.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure why I didn't think of this as a work-around. Will have to do for now. (BTW: Incognito Mode, if you're in Chrome, will use a separate session so that you don't have to log out or switch browsers.)